# monotouch compass overlaying mapview

Tags: mkmapview, xamarin.ios, compass-geolocation, core-location

I need to display a small compass over the mapview.

Is there a standard way of achieving this? It obv needs to update as the direction the phone is pointed in changes.

w://

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 4.2, there doesn't appear to be a standard way to display a compass on an MKMapView.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html